# How do I add hover effects to a textarea placeholder?

Tags: html, css, hover, textarea, placeholder

So I have a text area, like this:

```css
textarea::placeholder:hover {color:black;}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength='220' placeholder='Say Something!'>
</textarea>
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: placeholder is not a DOM element .. put the hover before

Comment: You would style the placeholder when the _textarea_ is hovered: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/v6wsxbgL/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jtbhcLdg/

Comment: @DmitriTsoy Did you even test that?

Comment: Thank your help! Sorry if this question seemed a little bit stupid/obvious; I'm still learning :-)

Comment: @Turnip excuses jsfiddle didn't get updated as I expected (https://jsfiddle.net/jtbhcLdg/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for hover on the textarea first.

```css
textarea:hover::placeholder { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength='220' placeholder='Say Something!'>
</textarea>
```